# Cucumber testing on WSL2 not showing UI for Google Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm testing my Rails project and there are some problems when the test is running.

`cucumber features/test.feature`

I have installed `chromedriver` for WSL2 and the test can run fine. However, the browser showing up is not rendered at all, it only has a border and transparent body like this.
[image]

I can still open `google-chrome` and it is displayed correctly. And the project used to work on WSL1. I can also take screenshots when testing, it's just that the browser's UI is not rendered.

I have installed the driver for GPU as [stated in the WSL guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps) but the problem still persisted.

Has anyone encountered this problem and how can I fix it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you on Windows 11 with WSLg, using a third-party X server, or some other method?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I'm on Windows 11 and using WSL2, I think WSLg has already been installed along with WSL2 since I installed WSL2 from scratch.

Comment: Correct - And from your question is looks like it *is* installed, just that something is going wrong.

Comment: You mention that it "used to work on WSL1".  Was that on the same computer?  I didn't think it was possible (but I'm not sure I recall for sure) to run the Linux chromedriver on WSL1.  I thought you had to use the Windows Chrome and chromedriver in that environment?  At the very least, you wouldn't have had WSLg on WSL1, so what technique were you using there?  Is this the same system, just upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11?  WSL1 is still available under Windows 11, so does it *still* work under WSL1 under Windows 11?

Comment: Hi @NotTheDr01ds, it's the same project, but different computers. My old PC is using Windows 10 and WSL1. I use this guide (https://qxf2.com/blog/setup-linux-testing-environment-on-windows-using-wsl/) to link chromedriver from windows to wsl. I said it used to work on WSL1 to show that it may be a problem with the setup of WSL2, not the project itself. Do you have any idea why it happens? I have to use screenshot to verify test now lol